# Using a data binding expression in a css style

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, css

This may not be possible but thought i would ask.  Creating a Sharepoint webpart.  In the ascx file i have a style tag. Is there any way that i could do the following:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    outerDiv
    {        
       border: 1px solid Black;
       height:<%# webPartHeight %>;
       width:300px;
    }
</style>
```

where the value for height is set via a data binding expression (code behind property).  I tried it and when i inspected the style the height had no value set.  Any help appreciated either way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `DataBind()` in, say, `Page_Load` and it will bind your properties to the page and you can use the exact syntax you have there.

```
protected string webPartHeight { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webPartHeight = "400px";
    DataBind();
}
```